# Object's rotation behaves strange while using siderbar rotation sliders

Tags: transforms

For an object's rotation in the sidebar of 3d viewport(or in the 'Object Properties' tab of the object in the properties editor), using the Y slider gives strange results which neither matches local or global axis when the initial rotation values of other two axes are not 0(I've seen that X and Z sliders always matches the local X axis of the object and global Z axis of the object respectively). Why this happens? What is the logic of such rotation?
My Blender version is 2.81.

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes, after changing transform orientation to Gimbal and selecting the rotation tool from toolbar, I can see that rotation matches with the those sliders with the gimbal axes(Though I don't understand gimbal well yet! I've to study on it).